# How to order this by notificationDate --> val userRef = fireBaseDBManager.fireStore.collection(FIRE_BASE_USERS).document(userId)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I tried this:

```
val userRef = fireBaseDBManager.fireStore.collection(FIRE_BASE_USERS).document(userId).orderBy("notificationDate")
```

But IDE won't let me do that.

Answer (score 1):

It will not let you do that, because you're trying to call the [orderBy()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#orderBy(java.lang.String)) method on a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference), which is actually not possible because there is no such method in the class. You can however call that method on a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query) object. So to solve this, you either remove the call to `.document(userId)` and your code should look like this:

```
fireBaseDBManager.fireStore.collection(FIRE_BASE_USERS).orderBy("notificationDate")
```

Or you add another call to a sub-collection and your coled should look like this:

```
fireBaseDBManager.fireStore.collection(FIRE_BASE_USERS)
                           .document(userId)
                           .collection("sub-collection") //
                           .orderBy("notificationDate")
```

Comment: Hey Mustafa. Can I help you with other information?